# VisualVM Profiler: How to test CPU Time for a method with varying parameter sizes?

Tags: java, methods, profiler, visualvm, cpu-time

Suppose I have a method that can take in a parameter is size n (Like an array with size n); is it possible to investigate the CPU Times for the method with varying array sizes in an automated manner using VisualVM's Profiler?

**Currently I only know how to investigate a particular running instance, and even if I use a loop to repeat the method with increasing n, VisualVM's profiler can only tell me the accumulative CPU Time. Ideally, I will be able to plot a graph of CPU Time vs n, where n is the size of the parameter I pass into the method. Is this possible with VisualVM?**

Comment: What do you mean with the size of a parameter? The amount of memory it consumes?

Comment: for example, run a method with a dataset (for example an array) with size=1, size=2, size=3, and so on... afterwards I need a graph of CPUTime against size of dataset

Comment: I'm no VisualVM profiler expert (there are better alterntives). But I don't think it can make a distinction based on array size. If you want to get some performance impressions, just write a JMH microbenchmark and run it with various array sizes and check how much it impacts performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only tool I know that has this functionality out of the box is [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) with its [Complexity analysis](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/help/doc/advancedCpu/complexity.html):

[image]

You can configure a method and a script that calculates a number from its parameters (the complexity), in your case the script would just return the parameter itself.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler